# How to extract N byte from offset x of uint8_t *bytes in c language?

Tags: c

How can i extract bytes from offset **offset** of tvb with length length **length**? type of tvb is :

```
uint8_t *tvb;

uint8_t *extractBytes(uint8_t *tvb, guint8 offset, guint8 length)
{
    // do ...
    // extract bytes and return
}
```

I don't know how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say by writing code. Seriously: this is no coding service. Get a C book, that will show you how to use loops, function, variables and pointers. And `uint8_t *` is a pointer, not an array. Do you want to split the pointer to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allocate memory for the extracted bytes. Then it's a simple matter of copying the correct bytes:

```
uint8_t *extractBytes(uint8_t *tvb, guint8 offset, guint8 length)
{
    uint8_t *new = malloc (length);
    if (new) {
        mempcy (new, tvb+offset, length);
    }
    return new; /* Returns NULL on allocation failure */
}
```

Don't forget to `free()` the allocated memory once you are done using it.

Note that the `malloc()` call above allocates `length` number of *bytes*. If you want to allocate memory for elements that are larger than `uint8_t`, you will have to multiply the amount by the size of the element. To be on the safe side, and to guard against future changes, you can allocate the memory as follows:

```
new = malloc (length * sizeof *new);
```

Now, `sizeof *new` will always be the correct element size.

---

If you don't need to change the extracted bytes, and the original buffer (`tvb`) doesn't change while you're using the bytes, you can access them directly using something like:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    do_something (tvb[offset+i]);
}
```